# How to check all fields are empty in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

How to check all fields in the submit form `ng-submit="submit(field)"` is empty in controller.js? They consists of few textboxes and one select field.

I would want an alert box to occur if all fields are empty and select option is not selected, instead of individual validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's not exactly what you're asking about, may be `$pristine` is what you want? It's a flag on the form indicating whether the form has ever been edited. If someone typed and then cleared out a field, `$pristine` would still be false, however.

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="doSubmit()" ng-controller="FormController">
    <input ng-model="firstName" name="firstName" />

</form>
```

Then in your controller

```
.controller('FormController', function($scope){
    $scope.doSubmit = function(){
        if($scope.myform.$pristine){}
    }
})
```

Alternatively, you can set all your fields to `required="true"` and use the `$valid` flag on the form in the same way as described above.

Comment: $scope.myform.$pristine is undefined. I need to do anything else? No?

Comment: Did you name the form and the input element? Is the controller your accessing the $scope in in the right spot to have the form in its $scope? http://jsfiddle.net/1774oawr/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
ng-show="!yourfield.length"
```

Something like this:

```
<form name="yourform">
  <input name="yourfield" ng-model="somefield" ng-minlength="10" required>
  <span ng-show="!yourfield.myfield.$error.required">Something</span>
</form>
```

Comment: i would one a one time validation after submitting. If all fields are empty, an alert box will popup, instead of individual validation

Answer (score 0):

You should look for [Form Validation](http://product.moveline.com/angular-validation-part-1-form-basics.html) . Take a look at this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation).

```
<input name="name" class="form-control"
    ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Name" required>
  <div class="alert alert-danger"
    ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required">
    Please enter the name.
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will show an alert if all fields are empty

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('FormController', function($scope) {
  $scope.doSubmit = function(){
    if (formIsEmpty($scope.myform)){
      alert('You forgot to enter something before submitting');
    }
  };
  
  function formIsEmpty(form) {
    for (var prop in form) {
      if (!form.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { continue; }
      if (prop[0] === '$') { continue; }
      if ($scope[prop]) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <form name="myform" ng-submit="doSubmit()" ng-controller="FormController">
    <input ng-model="firstName" name="firstName" />
    <input ng-model="lastName" name="lastName" />
    <textarea ng-model="description" name="description"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine. But id doesn't work when we use form object. For eg. <input ng-model="user.firstName" name="firstName" /> OR <input ng-model="user.firstName" name="user.firstName" /> Can you please tell me how to do?